# Strange message in syslog regarding ufs filesystem

Tags: kernel, filesystem

I found this message in syslog:

```
ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

>>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
```

What should I do ?

Comment: You may want to follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/696328/strange-errors-in-dmesg-output-related-to-mounted-partition) question where the same error message came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is being triggered when running update-grub. It calls out to os-prober to determine if you have any alternative operating systems installed. The message occurs because a UFS mount fails because the partitions being probed are not actually in ufs format.

The error can be safely ignored.

A bug against os-prober is open on this very issue, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1374759