# Strange errors in 'dmesg' output related to mounted partition

Tags: mount, dmesg, ufs

There are some strange errors showing up in my `dmesg` output related to mounting `sda4` on boot, which is an extended partition containing used logical volumes.

The following is an extract of my `dmesg` output shortly after boot. I removed some `[UFW BLOCK]` firewall entries in between it though.

```
[  842.165660] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[  842.372589] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[  842.668365] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[  843.035074] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
[  843.288031] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  2212 MB/s
[  843.356052] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  1599 MB/s
[  843.424044] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  3118 MB/s
[  843.492027] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  1502 MB/s
[  843.560047] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  2975 MB/s
[  843.628024] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  1857 MB/s
[  843.628034] raid6: using algorithm sse2x2 gen() 3118 MB/s
[  843.628037] raid6: .... xor() 1502 MB/s, rmw enabled
[  843.628041] raid6: using intx1 recovery algorithm
[  843.660527] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[  843.700031]    prefetch64-sse:  3182.000 MB/sec
[  843.740020]    generic_sse:  3851.000 MB/sec
[  843.740028] xor: using function: generic_sse (3851.000 MB/sec)
[  843.869982] Btrfs loaded
[  845.893662] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[  845.896625] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[  845.900337] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[  845.903455] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[  845.903464] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[  845.912432] XFS (sda4): Invalid superblock magic number
[  845.919404] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[  845.919413] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[  845.927924] MINIX-fs: unable to read superblock
[  846.001284] attempt to access beyond end of device
[  846.001293] sda4: rw=16, want=3, limit=2
[  846.001300] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[  846.014902] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
[  846.018195] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

               mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

               >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[  846.024054] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sda4
[  890.554489] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[  890.557377] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[  890.560315] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[  890.563428] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[  890.563436] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[  890.573590] XFS (sda4): Invalid superblock magic number
[  890.579829] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[  890.579838] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[  890.591160] MINIX-fs: unable to read superblock
[  890.596813] attempt to access beyond end of device
[  890.596837] sda4: rw=16, want=3, limit=2
[  890.596876] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[  890.601952] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
[  890.607635] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

               mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

               >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[  890.613446] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sda4
[ 2111.590730] perf interrupt took too long (2505 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 2323.551898] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[ 2323.555029] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[ 2323.558560] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[ 2323.561654] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[ 2323.561662] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2323.570667] XFS (sda4): Invalid superblock magic number
[ 2323.577885] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[ 2323.577893] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2323.588531] MINIX-fs: unable to read superblock
[ 2323.594927] attempt to access beyond end of device
[ 2323.594937] sda4: rw=16, want=3, limit=2
[ 2323.594943] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 2323.599796] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
[ 2323.603466] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

               mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

               >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[ 2323.627446] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sda4
[ 2347.927763] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[ 2347.937927] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[ 2347.943278] EXT4-fs (sda4): unable to read superblock
[ 2347.954206] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[ 2347.954217] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2348.020480] XFS (sda4): Invalid superblock magic number
[ 2348.049075] FAT-fs (sda4): invalid media value (0xda)
[ 2348.049085] FAT-fs (sda4): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 2348.062423] MINIX-fs: unable to read superblock
[ 2348.066949] attempt to access beyond end of device
[ 2348.066959] sda4: rw=16, want=3, limit=2
[ 2348.066965] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
[ 2348.071702] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir).
[ 2348.076214] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

               mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

               >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[ 2348.095021] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sda4
```

Here some more information about my system (Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit) and partitions:

Output of `lsblk /dev/sda`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /win/boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    74G  0 part /win/c
├─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part /boot
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  31,3G  0 part /images
├─sda6   8:6    0    40G  0 part /
├─sda7   8:7    0    60G  0 part /home
├─sda8   8:8    0    15G  0 part /win/share
└─sda9   8:9    0   4,6G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Output of `sudo parted -l /dev/sda`:

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72102 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      106MB   79,6GB  79,4GB  primary   ntfs
 3      79,6GB  88,1GB  8590MB  primary   ext4
 4      88,1GB  250GB   162GB   extended
 6      88,1GB  131GB   42,9GB  logical   ext4
 7      131GB   196GB   64,4GB  logical   ext4
 8      196GB   212GB   16,1GB  logical   fat32
 9      212GB   217GB   4876MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 5      217GB   250GB   33,6GB  logical   ext4
```

Output of `mount | grep /dev/sda`:

```
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /win/boot type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /win/c type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda5 on /images type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda8 on /win/share type vfat (rw,relatime,gid=46,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

Content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=eee18451-b607-4875-8a88-c9cb6c6544c8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=6dbb8633-dadd-4b5e-8d85-b0895fde9dfb /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2

# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=485b3ef1-7216-4053-b25c-f656d529e8e6 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

# /images was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=81dc42c4-a161-4ccd-b704-6e5c09298943 /images         ext4    defaults        0       2


# /old partition image file of previous 15.04 installation
/images/backup/ubuntu-vivid-151028-ext4.img /old          ext4    defaults,ro


# /win/boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=90DCF3A5DCF3842E /win/boot       ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0

# /win/c was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=482C7A572C7A3FCC /win/c          ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0

# /win/share was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=B148-49F9  /win/share      vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1


# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=4b184fdc-fe7a-4019-92e4-8a6607fe7291 none            swap    sw              0       0


/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but the way I see it, the error messages apply to the small 1K space, not to the extended volume as a whole. That is why the mount command fails for sda4 but all your other partitions on that disk get mounted. Annoying, but not alarming.

Answer (score 2):

This might be late, but I found a debian bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794849

It looks like os-prober is the problem and it runs when a new kernel is installed. I've just tested an update on a system that did not have these entries in dmesg output before the update but they appeared after.